# Not understanding how setRetainInstance (or RetainInstance in Xamarin Android) works?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

If you have some `Fragment` declared right inside your XML layout file, then looks like `SetRetainInstance` works expectedly.

However what if the `Fragment` is loaded dynamically into some container in the `OnCreate` callback of the main `Activity`? I don't see how `setRetainInstance` means or can do in this case.

Check out this code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    var f = new SomeFragment();
    var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    ft.Replace(Android.Resource.Id.Content, f);
    ft.Commit();
}
```

You can see that everytime the `OnCreate` is called (such as when the screen is rotated), a new `SomeFragment` is created and fills the main content of the Activity.

Now even if I declare a variable (field) holding reference to the instance of fragment and create it only when it's null, something like this:

```
SomeFragment f;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    if(f == null) {
        f = new SomeFragment(this);
        f.RetainInstance = true;
    }
    var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    ft.Replace(Android.Resource.Id.Content, f);
    ft.Commit();
}
```

This also does not work, everytime the Activity is created, the field `f` is still null initially (not retained). The only solution I found working here is declare the field `f` as static, like this:

```
static SomeFragment f;
```

With that I don't even need to use `RetainInstance` (or `setRetainInstance` in Java). In fact the requirement of loading Fragments dynamically is very popular, so at that point `RetainInstance` seems to be less helpful?

Or I missed something simple here to still take advantage of `RetainInstance`? The problem is use `RetainInstance` and dynamically load Fragments, if you have some solution or pattern to use here, please share with me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I am not familiar to Xamarin, I can answer this in Java.

Instead of using

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
```

You should use

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

For example,

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExampleFragment fragment;
fragment = (ExampleFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag");
if(fragment == null)
    fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "tag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But you should only use `setRetainInstance` if you are running longe task at background. You may have a look at [this blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html). Recreating the fragment is more suggested as it can avoid unexpected behavior (e.g. not initializing some variables).

Comment: yes looks like it works, so with your solution we aslo don't need to use `setRetainInstance` (although the purpose seems to be similar). Thanks for your suggestion about when we should actually use `setRetainInstance`. For my use case, I just need to manage all opened Fragments and switch between them without having to manually maintain states and re-run some code everytime a fragment is switched to.

Comment: Well, I've just tried experiencing it more, the `Fragment` instance can be found OK (some kind of being retained) but we still need to use `setRetainInstance` to prevent the Fragment from being re-created (using the default parameterless constructor). The constructor is surely called but somehow it is still found by tag using FragmentManager, the View's state (such as text of some EditText) is still retained, data members (defined in Fragment class) however are not retained.